# ReactRouter: Can not read property "imageId" of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to use React Router for a react-native project. In my index.js file I have:

```
  <NativeRouter>
    <View>
      <Route path="/" component={MainComponent} />
      <Route path="/images/:imageId/" component={ShowImage} />
    </View>
  </NativeRouter>
```

And in the DisplayComponent I have:

```
    <View}>
      {items.map( item => {
        return (
          <Link to="images/7326" key={item.id}>
            <Image
              source={{uri: 'https://someImageLink...'}}
            />
          </Link>
        )
      })}
    </View>
```

And show image looks like this:

```
export default class ShowImage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.props.params.imageId}</Text>
     </View>
   );
 }
}
```

When I click on a loaded image I get the following error:

```
can not read "imageId" of undefined.
```

So I am guessing the props arent being passed in but cant figure out where... Thanks for all the help.

Comment: What is the URL of the page when you see the error?

Comment: Try changing the `path` in the router to `/images/:imageId` and the `to` in the Link to `/images/7326`

Comment: Its a react-native app so I am not sure how to check the url..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest version of `react-router`, which I am guessing you are using, the route params are available from the `match` prop. So in order to get the `imageId`

Use

```
  <Text>{this.props.match.params.imageId}</Text>
```