# How to get params in component in react router dom v4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have this code:

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <Route  path="/(:filter)?" component={App} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

the filter param or '' on the root is suppose to be on App components' props base on the previous react router versions?

This is my code on my App:

```
const App = ({params}) => {
    return ( // destructure params on props
      <div>
        <AddTodo />
        <VisibleTodoList 
            filter={params.filter || 'all'} // i want to git filter param or assign 'all' on root 
        />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
}
```

I logged this.props.match.params on console but it has none? help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactRouter: Can not read property "imageId" of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44294006/reactrouter-can-not-read-property-imageid-of-undefined)

Comment: I want to accept this as duplicate but I am using regexp here, I think it's because of regexp that nothing is passed on my params, I have logged props.match.params but all I get is empty object even though I have a working react router, accessing location pathname does the same for me so I have to do what's necessary in my situation but I would appreciate suggestions since I have to move on with this since I have tried to fix this for hours

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I assume you are following the [Redux tutorial on Egghead.io](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-filtering-redux-state-with-react-router-params), as your example code seems to use what is defined in that video series. I also got stuck on this part trying to integrate React Router v4, but eventually found a working solution not far from what you have tried.

> ⚠️ NOTE: one thing I would check here is that you are using the
>   current version of `react-router-dom` (`4.1.1` at the time of this
>   writing). I had some issues with optional filters in the params on
>   some of the alpha and beta versions of v4.

First, some of the answers here are incorrect, and you indeed *can* use optional params in React Router v4 without the need for regular expressions, multiple paths, archaic syntax, or using the `<Switch>` component.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Route  path="/:filter?" component={App} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Second, as others have noted, React Router v4 no longer exposes `params` on route handler components, but instead gives us a `match` prop to use.

```
const App = ({ match }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <AddTodo />
        <VisibleTodoList filter={match.params.filter || 'all'} />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )
}
```

From here, there are two ways to keep your content in sync with the current route: using `mapStateToProps` or using the HoC `withRouter`, both solutions are already talked about in the Egghead series so I won't recapitulate them here.

If you are still having trouble, I urge you to check out my repository of the completed application from that series.

- [Here is the commit using the `mapStateToProps` solution](https://github.com/indiesquidge/idiomatic-redux/commit/43427da3b6ebcad4fa2837f23dfe0b40bade1122)
- [Here is the commit using the `withRouter` soluiton](https://github.com/indiesquidge/idiomatic-redux/commit/fdf8609167ebb4418958f15e22f4eebb2a71b4ed)

Both of which seem to work fine (I just tested both of them).

Comment: [This](https://github.com/indiesquidge/idiomatic-redux/commit/fdf8609167ebb4418958f15e22f4eebb2a71b4ed) is a great solution to get parameters from url without additional code. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

React Router v4 does not accept a regex for the path. You won't find regular expressions covered anywhere in the documentation. Instead of a regex you can just create multiple routes inside the `<Switch>` component and the first one that matches will be rendered:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route  path="/" component={App} />
    <Route  path="/:filter" component={App} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

You also have a bug in your App component. You get the params via the match property, not the params property (not tested, but this should be closer to what you want):

```
const App = ({match}) => {
    return ( 
      <div>
        <AddTodo />
        <VisibleTodoList 
            filter={match.params.filter || 'all'} 
        />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
}
```

All of the above is covered in the [React Router V4 docs on ambiguous matches](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/ambiguous-matches)

Answer (score 3):

From the [`react-router` documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params), `props.match.params` is where your parameteres are stored.

So to access the filter name, try this

```
const App = ({match}) => {
    ...
    <VisibleTodoList 
        filter={match.params.filter || 'all'}
    />
    ...
}
```

Comment: Remove the regular expression from your `Route` component. Make it just `Route path="/:filter".

Comment: I tried it but It will crash my app, I used that since it's an optional param, but I do not know why react router cannot detect my filter even though it's working, I resolved it using location.pathname since it does the work for me

Comment: Sorry, I misread the documentation. What about if you do `path="/:filter?"`?. So no parenthesis but keep the question mark.

Comment: just the same. react router won't detect

Answer (score 3):

I know the question is about v4, but if sm looks for v5, we can use the `useParams` hook.

```
// /:filter
const {filter} = useParams();
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the params in the path URL

```
//to your route component  
<Route path={`${match.url}/upload/:title`} component={FileUpload}/> 
=====
//Parent component
<Link to={`${match.url}/upload/css`}>  
=====
//Child component  
const {params: {title}} = this.props.match;
console.log(title);

result = css
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why react router cannot detect my filter even though it's working properly, I resolved this problem by using location.pathname since it does the work for me. I think react router cannot detect my filter param because of regexp, I expected that so I put || to use all on root, but unfortunately for me I it cannot detect so I used location.pathname . I would appreciate suggestions on this since I am not sure with my path configuration on regexp.