# How to get query params in React which are being generated from state

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I´ve seen several posts regarding this but they all seem getting their pararms from a fixed one. Example:

```
<Link to=`/lista/:idList`}> <button>Go To List</button> </Link>
```

Then you can get them doing this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.match.params);
 }
```

But what about if in my App I have it like this:

```
 <Link to={`/lista/${this.state.url_lista}`}> <button>Go To List</button> </Link>
```

The param depends on the state of the parent component (`CreateList.js`), when I click *Go To List* the App goes to the Child component (`TheList.js`). If I want to get the params (basically, `this.state.url_lista`) then I can not do the above, can I?

Also I can not pass state from a parent to a child right?

This is the code of both components:

```js
export default class CreateList extends Component {
  state = {
    listaIsCreated: false,
    lista: "",
    url_lista: ""
  }

  createList = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    this.setState({
      listaIsCreated: true,
      lista: event.target.elements.titulolista.value
    })

    const tituloLista = event.target.elements.titulolista.value;
    axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/list', {
      title: tituloLista
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)

        let id_newList = res.data._id;

        this.setState({
          url_lista: id_newList
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
      })
  }

  render() {
          </div>
              <Link to={`/lista/${this.state.url_lista}`}> <button>Go To List</button> </Link>
            </div>

      )
    }
  }
}
```

```js
export default class TheList extends React.Component {

    state = {
        titulo_lista: ""
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.match.params);
         // Do get request using the url params
     }
    
        render(){
            return (
               
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If, as you described, `TheList` is a child of `CreateList`, then you could pass the prop from parent to child. But in your code example, both code files seem to be unrelated, there is no `<TheList>` inside the `<CreateList>` render function.

I suspect that the actual connection between both might be hidden inside `React Router`, as your code seems to get `props.match` from somewhere. Have you tried, if your solution is not working? If [React Router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) handles the URL, and if `/lista/:idList` is defined as a route, with `:idList` being a parameter, it should be accessible in something like `props.match.params.idList`. See [How to get params in component in react router dom v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471437/how-to-get-params-in-component-in-react-router-dom-v4).

Another, now recommended, way to share information between components even if they are not coupled as parent and child, is the [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: I see. Yeah there is no relation between the two apart from being used with React Router. I´ll probably have to do it with React context, thanks.

Comment: Hi @J.Cake if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.location.hash.split('/').pop()`

Comment: Doesn´t return anything :S