# import error: 'useParams' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2" but the useParams not working what should I do?

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import DATA from '../Data';

const ProductDetail = () => {
    {/* Now we need a product id which is pass from the product page. */}
    const proid = useParams();
    const proDetail = DATA.filter(x => x.id == proid.id)
    const product = proDetail[0];
    console.log(product);
```

Answer (score 3):

As @slideshowp2 Mentioned, your **react-router-dom** version should be equals to or greater than 5.1

Update your to react-router-dom to the latest version using the following command

```
npm i react-router-dom@latest
```

Or update it to the specific version

```
npm install react-router-dom@5.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

`useParams`, `useLocation`, `useHistory`, and `useRouteMatch` hooks were added  since `react-router` [v5.1.0](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/releases/tag/v5.1.0)

For react-router-dom v4.x about how to get the URL params, there are many questions already:

- [How to get params in component in react router dom v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471437/how-to-get-params-in-component-in-react-router-dom-v4)

For react-router-dom v5.1.0+, you can use `useParams` hook to get the URL params: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v5-useparams-fmw9k?file=/src/BlogPost.js), you can change the URL to `https://fmw9k.csb.app/blog/joke` and see the logs in the console.

Comment: "react-router": "^5.2.1",
i've added react router but still the same error

Comment: @AgusRifaldi I made an example using `react-router-dom` v5.1.0+