# Redirect from a route having path params in react-router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-redux, react-router-v4

I am trying to redirect from one url with ID to a new one with the same ID: `/folders/:id` TO `/folders/:id/summary`

My issue is that my container `FolderSummaryContainer` seems to never be called :-/

Here is my react router configuration (v4), I am doing it right?

```
{/* STUF */}
<Route path="/v3">
  <LayoutV3>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/v3/folders" component={FolderIndexContainer} />
      <Route path="/v3/folders/:id">
        <FolderShowContainer>
          <Switch>
            <Redirect from="/v3/folders/:id" to="/v3/folders/:id/summary" />
            <Route path="/v3/folders/:id/summary" component={FolderSummaryContainer} />
            {/* STUF */}
          </Switch>
        </FolderShowContainer>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </LayoutV3>
</Route>
{/* STUF */}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't specify children to the Route , rather you can do it like

```
<Route path="/v3">
  <LayoutV3>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/v3/folders" component={FolderIndexContainer} />
      <Route path="/v3/folders/:id" component={FolderShowContainer}/>
    </Switch>
  </LayoutV3>
</Route>
```

You can have the route config then defiend in your FolderShowContainer Return code itself

```
class FolderShowContainer extends React.Component {
     render() {
        return (
            <div>
             {/* */}
             <Switch>
                 <Redirect from="/v3/folders/:id" to="/v3/folders/:id/summary" />
                 <Route path="/v3/folders/:id/summary" component={FolderSummaryContainer} />
                 {/* STUF */}
             </Switch>
            </div>
         )
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a try, thank you. FYI, we are migrating from the `react-router` v3 to the v4, we liked the old way because all the routes are in the same file... If possible we want to keep it like that.

Comment: Even I peferred that way, but in the current version, things have changed :)

Comment: much things changed in this major version... somes are pretty cool and others a bit tricky :-p

Comment: have you any idea on how to I get the `:id` when I redirect ? the redirection works well now, but it redirect to `/folders/:id/summary` instead of `/folders/42/summary`. should I use the `withRoutes` decorator + `match` prop ?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44294006/reactrouter-can-not-read-property-imageid-of-undefined/44301096#44301096 and yes make useof withRouter